# Incrementing the value of item in list<keyvaluepair<string, int>> if key already exists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `keyvaluepair<string, int>`.

When I am adding to the list, I check if the key already exists, I increment the count of value to +1. If not, I add the new (key,1). This is how I am doing it now. Is there a better and neat way to do it. I am new to LINQ, but liking it very much.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> kvp = myList.Where(x => x.Key.ToLower() == name.ToLower());
if (kvp == null || kvp.Count() == 0)
{
    //Add first occurence
    myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(name, 1));
}
else
{
    //Update occurence count +1 and add the new key
    //TODO : Refactor
    KeyValuePair<string, int> updatedKVP = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(name, kvp.FirstOrDefault().Value + 1);
    myList.Remove(kvp.FirstOrDefault());
    myList.Add(updatedKVP);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there's a much cleaner way to do it: use a `Dictionary<string, int>`. However, we don't really have enough context to help you rewrite.

Comment: Or create a proper Data Model to store your data. `List<Tuple<KeyValuePair<int, string>,double,triple, quadruple>>` <- that sucks. Create a proper Data Model.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have moved to use Dict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're keeping a list of kvps because of case sensitivity.

Here's an alternative:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if(dict.ContainsKey(name))
{
   dict[name] += 1;
}
else
{
   dict[name] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I will try moving this to dictionary now. I am sure I had a reason. Cant recollect now. But, will give this a try again. Thanks for looking.